# Routing to an index partition in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html#routing-index-partition) of elasticsearch, `routing_partition_size` can be set at an index level during index creation. This allows us to index documents under a custom routing value to a subset of shards, which allows us to distribute data across shards at the expense of searching more shards per request. Alternatively, if `routing_partition_size` is not specified, we run the risk of ending up with an imbalanced cluster since each document under a routing value is only indexed to a single shard.

My question is: Why is the setting only allowed to be configured on an index level? For example, consider the scenario of having a collection of docs, where each doc represent a product in inventory belonging to a particular supplier.

We index each doc using supplier_code as the custom _routing value. The majority of suppliers have sufficiently less inventory, so it is reasonable to store all the docs under `small` suppliers within one shard (i.e not using routing_partition_size)

However, there are a handful of large suppliers which contain sufficiently adequate inventory. We would like to index the docs under `large` suppliers to a subset of shards (i.e using routing_partition_size). This would prevent certain shards from becoming bottle-neck for search queries for large suppliers.

With the current configuration of elasticsearch, I can only decide to use routing_partition_size at the index level, which means I will be required to search multiple shards for small sellers as well (which is not ideal).

It appears that the purpose of `routing_partition_size` to distribute docs in a shard (with potentially multiple _routing keys) across shards but in doing so, it prevents us from only using a subset of routing keys to be distributed across shards.

Comment: Why not have separate indices with different settings for small and large tenants?

Comment: I don't want to create separate indices for small/large tenants because cross-index communication will be expensive operation

Comment: What kinds of cross-tenant queries do you have?

Comment: Cross tenant queries can include comparison of inventory and prices, etc. In general, it's better to have everything within 1 index to reduce indexing volume as well. I'm thinking to write my own custom routing logic for large/small tenants but I just wanted to check if there's any built in option in elastic which will let me do it.

Comment: You can run a query against multiple indices `GET /INDEX_1,INDEX_2/_search ...` it would be significantly more maintainable than the manual routing.